# Angular 2: How can I reinitialize a plugin (directive) with options?

Tags: angular

I am still fairy new to Angular 2 so might be missing some fundamentals here.

I am using the [ngx-slimscroll](https://github.com/jkuri/ngx-slimscroll) plugin to create a custom scrollbar on a div. The issue is that the div will contain dynamically-added content, and so its height will vary. Since the plugin's scrollbar is set at a static height, I need to reinitialize the plugin on the event of new content being added.

In my template:

```
<div slimScroll [options]="slimScrollOptions">
  // variable content
</div>
```

And in the component it's just a case of setting the options:

```
public slimScrollOptions: ISlimScrollOptions = environment.slimscrollConfig;
```

So my question (I think) is a more fundamental one: How do you tell Angular to reload/reinitialze the directive when it is set in this way?

I hope my question is clear- thanks in advance